# How are kernel space segfaults detected by the kernel?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, segmentation-fault

In C, if you try to write to memory thats not yours, one possible thing that can happen is a segfault. (Technically, the behavior is undefined when you try to write to memory thats not yours but one of the ways a OS can handle such a situation is by throwing a segfault). For user space code that attempts an illegal memory access, the kernel is the one that detects the illegal memory access and throws the segfault.

Now, I'm writing a Linux kernel module. My code runs in kernel space. I have two related questions:

1. If I go out of bounds of an array, my code segfaults. I want to know what is detecting this segfault? For user space applications, the kernel detects segfaults. What about for the kernel code itself? What is responsible for detecting out of bounds memory access in kernel code?
2. Does the kernel module that I write and insmod run as a separate process? If yes, why does the whole kernel segfault when my module segfaults? Why doesn't just my module segfault, and the rest of the kernel continue to run?

I'm reading Section 3.1.5 in this tutorial: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/lkmpg.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. A segmentation fault happens due to an illegal memory access. The kernel keeps track of what memory has been allocated, and if you attempt an access outside that allocation, it segfaults just as a userspace process would.
2. There's no notion of "processes" in the Linux kernel in the same way that there is in userspace (see [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/197168/is-kernel-a-process) for a good discussion of that). The kernel can spawn threads to handle certain tasks, but that's not the same thing. Effectively you can think of the kernel as one large "process" that stands or falls together.

Comment: Thanks! Follow up to your part 1 answer - you said, "The kernel keeps track of what memory has been allocated...". Does the kernel keep track of what memory has been allocated by other parts of the kernel? If yes, I'm curious to know what part of the kernel does this?

Comment: The component you're looking for is the [page allocator](https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand009.html). [Here's](http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/lk/lk-9.html) another good discussion of kernel memory management.

Answer (score 7):

Unlike higher level languages, memory accesses talk directly to the hardware in C. A load becomes this instruction: `mov %reg, [address]`. And a store becomes this: `mov [addr], value`. As the OS is not directly involved in the execution of this instruction, illegal accesses are caught by the processor. Here is how x86 responds to a write to a read-only mapping (from [Intel software developer manual](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html)):

```
MOV—Move
...
Protected Mode Exceptions
...
#GP(0) If the destination operand is in a non-writable segment.
...
```

For the hardware to detect illegal accesses, OS maintains page tables. Same with userspace, kernel mode has its memory mappings as well. Any access that falls outside the mappings generate an exception, which calls a handler within the OS.

For details you can check out **Vol.2 Chapter 4: Paging** in those manuals.